# Set state property from URL using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a container component with a modal in it that is opened and closed based on a state property.

I want to control this via the URL, i.e. I want to have

```
/projects - the modal is NOT open
/projects/add - the modal IS open
```

As well as being able to link directly to it, I want the URL to change when I click on links within the main container to open the modal.

Can someone explain how I could do this, or point me in the right direction of a good tutorial?

Comment: You can directly access the `params` and `pathname` by `this.props.params`, and perhaps reference it directly to manage the modals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** This way is not perfect. Even more it's rather antipattern than pattern. The reason I publish it here is it works fine for me and I like the way I can add modals (I can add modal to any page and in general their components don't depends on the other app in any way. And I keep nice url's instead of ugly `?modal=login-form`). But be ready to get problems before you find everything working. Think twice!

Let's consider you want following url's:

- `/users` to show `<Users />` component
- `/users/login` to show `<Users />` component and `<Login />` modal over it

You want `Login` to not depend on `Users` in anyway, say adding login modal to other pages without pain.

Let's consider you have kinda root component which stands on top of other components. For example `Users` `render` may look something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <UsersList />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

And `Layout`'s `render` may look something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="page-wrapper">
      <Header />
      <Content>
        {this.props.children}
      </Content>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The trick is to force modal's injection to `<Layout />` every time we need it.

The most simple approach is to use flux for it. I'm using redux and have `ui` reducer for such page meta-information, you can create `ui` store if you use other flux implementation. Anyway, final goal is to render modal if `<Layout />`'s state (or even better props) contains `modal` equal to some string representing modal name. Something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="page-wrapper">
      <Header />
      <Content>
        {this.props.children}
      </Content>
      {this.props.modal ?
        <Modal key={this.props.modal} /> :
        null
      }
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`<Modal />` returns modal component depends on given key (In case of our `login-form` key we want to receive `<Login />` component).

Okay, let's go to router. Consider following code snippet.

```
const modal = (key) => {
  return class extends React.Component {

    static displayName = "ModalWrapper";

    componentWillMount() {
      // this is redux code that adds modal to ui store. Replace it with your's flux
      store.dispatch(uiActions.setModal(key));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      store.dispatch(uiActions.unsetModal());
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Next">{this.props.children}</div>
      );
    }

  }
};

...
<Route path="users" component={Next}>
  <IndexRoute component={Users}>
  <Route path="login" component={modal('login-form')}>
    <IndexRoute component={Users} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

*(Don't care about `Next` - I add it here for simplicity. Imagine it just renders this.props.children)*

`modal()` function returns react component that triggers change in `ui` store. So as soon as router gets `/users/login` it adds `login-form` to `ui` store, `<Layout />` get it as prop (or state) and renders `<Modal />` which renders corresponding for given key modal.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically assess to a new URL, pass the [router to your component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#lifecycle-mixin) and use [push](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc). `push` for example will be call in the callback trigger by the user action.

When setting your router set a route to `/projects/:status`. then, in your component route, you can read the value of `status` using `this.props.param.status`. Read "[whats-it-look-lik](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router#whats-it-look-like)" from react-router for an example.